# How to prevent the label of a long equation running into the right margin?

Tags: equations, margins

I have an equation of the form

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:master}
f(x) = E
\end{equation}
```

where `E` is a long expression. The problem is that the label runs into the right margin.

What is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: The proper way is to rewrite the equation to make things fit, possibly spreading `E` across multiple lines. Without you showing `E`, this is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `amsmath` package and then

```
\begin{multline}\label{eq:master}
f(x) =\\
 E
\end{multline}
```